# Safari is not showing an SVG with Visibility hidden on parent but not children

Tags: svg, safari

SVG with visibility set to hidden but its children set to visible not loading in Safari. All other Chrome, Firefox, and IE are ok.

sample here

```css
svg {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid green
}
svg:hover {
 opacity: 0.5
}
.c {
visibility:hidden}
.c * {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>Need to create grid with 6 sided shape. Each shape needs a hover state and said hover state needs to be happen on the shape not the bounding box of the element.</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 279 322.16">
 <title>
  svg1
 </title>

 <g>
  <path d="M0 80.54 0 241.62 139.5 322.16 279 241.62 279 80.54 139.5 0 0 80.54z" class="cls-1" />
 </g>
</svg>
<br /><br />
<p>One way to achieve this is to have the SVG element Visibility set to hidden but then make the children of the SVG visible. </p>
<p style="color: red"> The problem i have is that in Safari, the SVG disapears. Have tried adding visibility=visible to each of the elements in the SVG and still safari won't show them. Any help on this would be much appeciated.</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 279 322.16" class="c">
 <title>
  svg2
 </title>

 <g>
  <path d="M0 80.54 0 241.62 139.5 322.16 279 241.62 279 80.54 139.5 0 0 80.54z" class="cls-1" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Report a bug [to webkit](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: Why not doing `.cls-1:hover {
 opacity: 0.5
}`

Answer (score 0):

For me helps to replace **visibility: hidden/visible** to  **opacity: 0 / 1**.